# How to send a message to all quickblox Online users

Tags: ios, quickblox, quickblox-android

How to send a message to all online quickblox users. its is possible without receipientId to send a messages. Please tell me the solution.

Comment: receipientId - with out this how the user will recive the messge

Comment: Hi @Anbu.Karthik. i am asking to send the some information to all quickbox  online users. so without receipient id mention it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the details in below link: https://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-messages_users-ios

> 1. Broadcasting the same message to all users. It's a simple method which can be used in informational apps that do not authenticate users and where same push notification messages are broadcasted to everybody. This way when you want to send a push message you may 1) simply go to Admin panel -> Push Notifications -> type your message in Simple mode -> and hit "Send" for all of your users to receive the message; 2) Send a push using Push Notifications API (explained below). Following this way you only need to create ONE QuickBlox User which will have all of your users' devices associated with it. Then simply send your pushes to that User.

https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk/issues/239